# Dynamically add textboxe(s) on webform with attributes.add(onload..)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have searched for similar cases but can't find any that matches mine and I'm not that good with js, jquery and general website flow to figure this out myself.

I'm dynamically adding textboxes like this:

```
        var nr = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
        var c1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
        var c2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
        c1.InnerText = Q.Trim(new char[] { '{', '$', '[', ']', '}' }).TrimStart(new char[] { '-' });
        c2.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "tb_" + c.ToString(), ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static });
        var dateControl = c2.Controls[0] as TextBox;
        dateControl.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
        dateControl.Attributes.Add([event here], "initiateDateControl('"+ dateControl.ID + "')");
```

Currenty I'm using "onclick" for [event here] but I want onload or something similar.

```
function initiateDateControl(dateControl) {
    $("#" + dateControl).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeYear: true
    });
}
```

That is because onload doesn't work but onclick works. How can I load the jquery-datepicker when the page loads?

I'm not sure if I can add a body because all the controls is inside an asp:Content.

Comment: I could not find onload here in your code. Please give more information.

Comment: @Lafontein question updated.

Comment: try to put the onload call on the <body> element or just put it in a <script> tag.

Comment: But I can't create an onload function in the script tag because the textbox get created after the page is loaded.

Comment: Maybe you will change load priority somehow. I can not help in this situation sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround will be give a unique CssClass for all the controls like this

```
c2.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { 
    ID = "tb_0", 
    CssClass="my_tb", 
    ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static });
```

You could then call it on DOM ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".my_tb").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Or you could use jQuerys [Attribute Starts with Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id^='tb_']").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I also found out that:  `dateControl.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "initiateDateControl('" + dateControl.ID + "')");` worked, just not that beautiful.